# How to share a secret between distributed Windows applications without saving it to the assembly?

Tags: c#, windows, encryption, cryptography

I have a distributed Windows application - multiple IIS web sites and windows services on different machines.

I need to encrypt sensitive user data (like third-party API credentials) and then decrypt to use it in the applications.

The goal of this encryption - to prevent users with restricted access to database and file system (e.g. read-only access) to be able to access the sensitive admin-only credentials.

Obviously, I need my applications to share a common secret (private key) to be able to encrypt in one application and decrypt in another.

I'm considering an option to distribute this key as a part of the installers, but this approach will make installers by themselves sensitive. Since they're distributed through unsafe "business channels", I want to avoid it.

Something what I think I'm looking for - is a signature on my installers which will be checked by the target Windows machine, and which will give me access to built-in mechanisms to encrypt-decrypt the data. Something like [ProtectedData.Protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.protect?view=netframework-4.8), but with `DataProtectionScope` not limited to the user or machine. Ideally, it should be scoped to the company.

Comment: Please don't ignore paid solutions as well.

Comment: There are services which allows you to store your secrets. Depending on how you release your product, you might want to store it on the environment. In your case, the server's environment and keep it away from your distributed application. This question is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

I have some new thoughts, so it can already count as an answer (not a final solution, though).

If I will generate new public/private key pair during installation, and then store it on the machine, it will do the job for one machine. The question now is how to exchange this key securely between applications on different machines.

Older [Crypto API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/cryptographic-key-storage-and-exchange) have this quote:

> This would be easier if the respective CSPs could communicate
>   directly, but they cannot. Because CSPs cannot communicate, the key
>   has to be exported from one CSP, transmitted to the destination
>   application, and then imported into the destination CSP. This process
>   can become more complicated if the communication path is not trusted.

The newer [CNG doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/key-import-and-export) have this phrase:

> You can import and export symmetric keys and asymmetric keys with CNG.
>   And you can use key export and import functionality to **move keys
>   between machines**.

So looks like transition of trust between Windows machines is a part of the installation process. For example, after installation one can propose the user to export private key and then use it in the slave installation process.